# How to write a GraphQL update mutation for sql db (Apollo Server)

Tags: sql, graphql, apollo

I am trying to write an update mutation for my front end.

Here is what I have
Resovler:

```
    async updateUser(root, { id, name, email, password }, { models }) {
      return models.User.update(
        {
          id,
          name,
          email,
          password
        },
        {
          where: { id: id }
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Schema:

```
    updateUser(
      id: Int!
      name: String!
      email: String!
      password: String!
    ): User!
```

Calling this on the front end returns an error: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id."- then after a page refresh, the change is reflected.

This is what I call on the front end:

```
          updateUser({
            variables: {
              id: props.item.id,
              name: changeText,
              email: props.item.email,
              password: "password"
            }
          });
```

I believe in the mutation I am not returning it the correct way. Thank you.

Comment: What does `models.User.update` return? Some ORMs return a boolean to indicate that the INSERT/UPDATE operation was successful, while others actually return the mutated record. You'll need to make sure that the result of `models.User.update` returns data in the shape and type that GraphQL expects.

Comment: In my schema, it returns a User, just like my create mutation does which works fine. For some reason the updater returns nothing. Added schema above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by awaiting the change and then explicitly returning the args.

```
 async updateUser(root, { id, name, email, password }, { models }) {
      await models.User.update(
        {
          id,
          name,
          email,
          password
        },
        {
          where: { id: id }
        }
      );
      return { id, name, email, password }
    }
```